# Irregular bar spacing in barplot using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I want to make a barplot in using ggplot2 where all of values in the data get their own bar on the x-axis. However, I get irregular spacing between the bars.

This is my code:

```
library("plyr")
dataTable <- count(player_data, "dpi")

ggplot(dataTable, aes(x = dpi, y = freq, fill = dpi)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 20)
```

And this is the output:
[image: ggplot2 Barplot]

Instead of plotting on a range of `x` values, I want to plot for the specific values of 'x' like a base R barplot does, like this:

[image: Basic Barplot]

Comment: ggplot thinks you want a continuous x axis because `dpi` is numeric. You wish to treat `dpi` as a factor on the x axis for plotting purposes. Try `ggplot(dataTable, aes(x = factor(dpi), freq, fill = dpi)) + geom_col()`

Comment: Try `+ x_scale_discrete()` at the end.

Comment: I can't find a duplicate for this question, other than [How to plot only the respective values ​for each bar in ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72953599/how-to-plot-only-the-respective-values-for-each-bar-in-ggplot), which has no answer.

Comment: @AllanCameron Thank you very much. Adding `factor(dpi)` has solved my query.